# Where do my sound recordings get stored and how can I get them off my phone?

Tags: 8.1, storage, file-transfer

I have been using [this](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/recorder-p-ro/531c806d-bba8-445c-bd54-f83845c146fa) app to record rough vocals on my phone. It has the option to export to OneDrive but I don't want to do that. I can "save to library" and it then appears as a music track on my phone which can be synced to my PC, but I really just want to be able to find the original recording and copy it onto my PC!

It's partly an app-specific question but maybe apps are supposed to follow the same rules - how can I get access to these files?

Answer (score 3):

It will be in this directory - `Phone\Music\Me\RecorderPro`. I have the RecorderPro application as well and this is where my files are being stored. Once you connect your phone to your PC just navigate to that directory. If you load the ["Files"](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/apps/Files/9WZDNCRFJ3PL) application on your phone you can view your phone's files and directories through the application (though this application will not send files to your PC it is just to manage and view files through your phone's UI).

Comment: Ah - I _looked_ there before but it didn't show. Maybe it just takes time for it to be visible... I've seen when syncing music it can take a while to catch up.

Answer (score 2):

Apps are sandboxed to their own space, and you cannot access their files any way other than through the app. In this case it sounds as if your only option is to save to OneDrive or your Music library.

Comment: So apps get their own private storage space? The thing is, I don't really know what my "music library" is... I can see all my music on my phone through Windows Explorer, so should anything in my Music library become visible here?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Your music library is the Music folder on your phone or SD card. That is where the Xbox Music app gets its music from. (Well, that and the Xbox music store.) Basically when you "save to library", it copies the file from the app storage to the Music folder.